# Dockerized node.js and bind mount permission problem

Tags: docker, docker-compose, node.js, permissions

I have an interesting problem with node, docker-compose and local development using bind mounts.

I have a bind mount volume, called www-public, owned by my host node user (I created a node user and chowned the dir to node:node). The container (official node) is set up so it also run as node user. At some point in my node app, i need to write to this folder and i get the permission error. This seems strange at first, but it makes sense, because i figured then, that my host nodeuser has an uid of 1001 while my container node user has an id of 1000. If i just add this line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN usermod -u 1001 node && groupmod -g 1001 node
```

The permission problem goes away.

How do i fix this in a way, that I don't hard code the container node user id to match the node user id on the host like i did with the upper RUN command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile:

```
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

RUN usermod -u $UID node && groupmod -g $GID node
```

Then using `docker build`:

```
docker build --build-arg UID=$(id -u) --build-arg GID=$(id -g) .
```

The `ARG` lines provide defaults. If you leave off the `--build-arg` flags, they will be used. If you do use the `--build-arg` flags values those will be used instead.

Comment: Thx, both answers are useful. I will add args with defaults to Dockerfile, then override them in compose file for local dev. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The Compose syntax [allows you to specify](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) `user: <uid>:<gid>` in the service's configuration block.

For example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  node-service:
    image: node
    user: 1001:1001
```

This will run the container as UID 1001 and GID 1001.